# Setting up a bounds-protected array

Tags: c, windows, linux, mmu

I'd like to allocate an array and set it up such that the pages before and after it are protected by the memory management unit, so an attempt to run over the bounds of the array will be automatically caught; and then catch it in order to handle the error in a controlled fashion.

I doubt there will be a portable solution, but what's the best platform specific method using Microsoft C on Windows and GCC on Linux respectively?

Comment: There's [a Windows API function that actually used to do something like that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/10/10266256.aspx), although the behavior was removed in Windows Vista because people kept reporting it as a security vulnerability even though it's not.

Comment: The memory management unit works in page granularity and you may allocate arrays which are not terminated on page boundaries - in that case invalid access to memory between the end of the array and the page boundary won't be detected.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the mechanism used by that function is still available, though? That looks like the solution for Windows. - And yes, I figure I'll need to make sure to allocate the arrays in question on page boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a portable way to detect memory allocation overruns in software.  [Dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com) provides fencepost overwrite detection

> Fence-post memory is the area immediately above or below memory
>   allocations. It is all too easy to write code that accesses above or
>   below an allocation - especially when dealing with arrays or strings.
>   The library can write special values in the areas around every
>   allocation so it will notice when these areas have been overwritten.

http://dmalloc.com/docs/latest/online/dmalloc_17.html#SEC22

Comment: Right, thanks, that looks like a good portable solution for debugging purposes? What I'm looking for, though, is something deterministic that I can use to take out some of the explicit checks from the inner loop of an interpreter.

Comment: You could also extend or customize the GCC Compiler for your purpose (with a plugin or a MELT extension). http://gcc-melt.org/ might be a relevant tool to do that.